# Как сделать блоки одной высоты для десктоп версии и одной ширины для мобильной версии?

Tags: css, bootstrap, flexbox

Всем привет. Имеется вот такая вёрстка на Bootstrap 4. Есть стилизованные "Radio", и в зависимости от количества текста внутри "label" высота у этих блоков разная, также при переключении на мобильную версию, ширина блоков тоже может быть разная... Может это и простой вопрос, и где-то написано решение, но я не могу внятное найти, как сделать так, чтобы высота этих блоков была одинаковой равняясь по самому большому, а при переключении на мобильную версию ширина блоков была одинакова по самому большому или тупо по всей ширине экрана... Подскажите пожалуйста. Желательно максимально дефолтными классами от Bootstrap 4(по возможности).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style>
    .radio_example {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .radio_example input[type=radio] {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .radio_example label {
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 0.5em 1em;
      line-height: 34px;
      transition: .3s;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    .radio_example input[type=radio]:checked+label {
      background: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card shadow-sm mb-3">
    <div class="card-body pt-3 text-left">
      <h5 class="mt-4">
        Title 1
      </h5>
      <hr class="my-3">
      <div class="form-check radio_example my-1">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1_1" value="a">
        <label class="form-check-label rounded border" for="radio1_1">
           <div class="pt-2">
           Lorem Ipsum is.
           </div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check radio_example my-1">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1_2" value="b">
        <label class="form-check-label rounded border" for="radio1_2">
            <div class="pt-2">Lorem Ipsum  <br>is simply text.</div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check radio_example my-1">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1_3" value="c">
        <label class="form-check-label rounded border" for="radio1_3">
            <div class="pt-2">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy<br>text of the printing and<br>typesetting industry.
            </div>
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такс сделал, только крохотный css всё же внёс.
Остальное всё в html - классами bootstrap как и хотели.
Этот класс "flex-md-column" переход в мобилку, сами подстроите как вам нужно, вместо md может у вас sm.

```css
.form-check {
  padding-left: 1.25rem; // нужно убрать этот стиль
}
.card-body {
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style>
    .radio_example {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .radio_example input[type=radio] {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .radio_example label {
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 0.5em 1em;
      line-height: 34px;
      transition: .3s;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    .radio_example input[type=radio]:checked+label {
      background: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card shadow-sm mb-3">
    <h5 class="mt-4">Title 1</h5>
    <hr class="my-3">
    <div class="card-body pt-3 text-left d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-column">
      <div class="form-check radio_example my-1 border mw-100 d-flex">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1_1" value="a">
        <label class="form-check-label rounded mw-100" for="radio1_1">
           <div class="pt-2">
           Lorem Ipsum is.
           </div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check radio_example my-1 border mw-100 d-flex">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1_2" value="b">
        <label class="form-check-label rounded mw-100" for="radio1_2">
            <div class="pt-2">Lorem Ipsum  <br>is simply text.</div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check radio_example my-1 border mw-100 d-flex">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1_3" value="c">
        <label class="form-check-label rounded mw-100" for="radio1_3">
            <div class="pt-2">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy<br>text of the printing and<br>typesetting industry.
            </div>
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Очень помогли.  Только я немного доработал под свою задачу.  Не стал делать это -  "width: max-content" т.к. у меня тогда блоки над всем контентом выходили, не красиво. Далее, "flex-md-column" заменил на "flex-row" иначе у меня все в колонку вставало и не работал "inline-block", и последнее, классы "mw-100" заменил на "w-100", т.к. "max-width" - не работал и у блока "radio_example" вообще убрал этот класс, т.к. все в колонку вставало также. Добавил медиа стиль "@media (max-width: 992px)" где указал ширину "radio_example" = 100%. Спасибо за помощь ;)

Comment: @Studlara просто просили в классах bootstrap желательно, поэтому. Так бы стилями просто сделал всё)). Рад что помог

Comment: Ну понятно, я взял ваш образец за основу и немного доработал, если бы получилось обойтись просто указанием размерности экрана md/sm/lg то так бы и сделал, но не всё так просто оказалось)